# Сделать кнопку не активной, если выбран первый элемент

Tags: javascript, функции, button

Необходимо сделать кнопку "создать" не активной в том случае, если выбрано одно из двух значений “Выбрать месяц”/“Выбрать год” или выбрано сразу два значения. У меня проблема в том, что кнопка не становится снова нормальной после добавления других значений.

```js
let header = document.createElement('div');
    let select1 = document.createElement('select');
    let select2 = document.createElement('select');
    let label1 = document.createElement('label');
    let label2 = document.createElement('label');
    let body = document.getElementById('kappa');
    let elem = document.getElementById('calendaric');
    let butCreate = document.createElement('button');
    let butDelete = document.createElement('button');

    let monthArray = ['Выбрать месяц',"Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
        "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"];

    let yearArray = ['Выбрать год','1980','1981','1982','1983','1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989','1990','1991','1992',
    '1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009',
        '2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019'];

    label1.textContent = 'Месяц: ';
    label2.textContent = ' Год: ';
    butCreate.textContent = 'Создать';
    butDelete.textContent = 'Удалить';
    butCreate.style.marginLeft = '7px';
    butDelete.style.marginLeft = '7px';

    //цикл для заполнения тега select массивом
    for(let i = 0;i<monthArray.length;i++){
        let monthArray_ = monthArray[i];
        let optionFill = document.createElement('option');
        optionFill.className = 'month';
        optionFill.textContent = monthArray_;
        optionFill.value = monthArray_;
        select1.appendChild(optionFill);
    }
    //цикл для заполнения тега select массивом
    for(let i = 0;i<yearArray.length;i++){
        let yearArray_ = yearArray[i];
        let optionFill = document.createElement('option');
        optionFill.className = 'year';
        optionFill.textContent = yearArray_;
        optionFill.value = yearArray_;
        select2.appendChild(optionFill);
    }

    // butDelete.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //
    // });

    //неактивность кнопки!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    if((select1.value = select1.children[0].value)||(select2.value = select2.children[0].value)){
        butCreate.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
        butCreate.addEventListener('click', function () {
            butCreate.removeAttribute('disabled');
            console.log('4');
        });

    body.insertBefore(header,elem);
    header.appendChild(label1);
    header.appendChild(select1);
    header.appendChild(label2);
    header.appendChild(select2);
    header.appendChild(butCreate);
    header.appendChild(butDelete);
```

```html
<body id = 'kappa'>
<div id = 'calendaric'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет обработчиков события изменения селектов, поэтому нельзя сделать кнопку снова активной

```
const enableButtonIfNeeded = () => {
  if (select1.value !== select1.children[0].value &&
      select2.value !== select2.children[0].value) {
    butCreate.removeAttribute('disabled')
  } else {
    butCreate.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
  }
}

select1.onchange = enableButtonIfNeeded;
select2.onchange = enableButtonIfNeeded;
```

**Полный пример**

```js
let header = document.createElement('div');
    let select1 = document.createElement('select');
    let select2 = document.createElement('select');
    let label1 = document.createElement('label');
    let label2 = document.createElement('label');
    let body = document.getElementById('kappa');
    let elem = document.getElementById('calendaric');
    let butCreate = document.createElement('button');
    let butDelete = document.createElement('button');

    let monthArray = ['Выбрать месяц',"Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
        "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"];

    let yearArray = ['Выбрать год','1980','1981','1982','1983','1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989','1990','1991','1992',
    '1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009',
        '2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019'];

    label1.textContent = 'Месяц: ';
    label2.textContent = ' Год: ';
    butCreate.textContent = 'Создать';
    butDelete.textContent = 'Удалить';
    butCreate.style.marginLeft = '7px';
    butDelete.style.marginLeft = '7px';

    //цикл для заполнения тега select массивом
    for(let i = 0;i<monthArray.length;i++){
        let monthArray_ = monthArray[i];
        let optionFill = document.createElement('option');
        optionFill.className = 'month';
        optionFill.textContent = monthArray_;
        optionFill.value = monthArray_;
        select1.appendChild(optionFill);
    }
    //цикл для заполнения тега select массивом
    for(let i = 0;i<yearArray.length;i++){
        let yearArray_ = yearArray[i];
        let optionFill = document.createElement('option');
        optionFill.className = 'year';
        optionFill.textContent = yearArray_;
        optionFill.value = yearArray_;
        select2.appendChild(optionFill);
    }

    // butDelete.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //
    // });

    //неактивность кнопки!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    if((select1.value = select1.children[0].value)||(select2.value = select2.children[0].value)){
        butCreate.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
    butCreate.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('It works!');
    });

    body.insertBefore(header,elem);
    header.appendChild(label1);
    header.appendChild(select1);
    header.appendChild(label2);
    header.appendChild(select2);
    header.appendChild(butCreate);
    header.appendChild(butDelete);
    
const enableButtonIfNeeded = () => {
  if (select1.value !== select1.children[0].value &&
      select2.value !== select2.children[0].value) {
    butCreate.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    butCreate.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
  }
}

select1.onchange = enableButtonIfNeeded;
select2.onchange = enableButtonIfNeeded;
```

```html
<body id = 'kappa'>
<div id = 'calendaric'></div>
```